# Start another lightdm service

Tags: lightdm, gui, services

There is one GUI already running using the `lightdm` service, is it possible to start another such GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Do ctrl+alt+fN where N is a number between 1 and 9 other than 7. For example: F2. It will drop you to text login. put in the username and password and at the prompt type "startx" (without the quotes). To get back to your main (default) login hit ctrl+alt+F7.